# Непереведенная строка в мобильной версии

Tags: дефект, локализация, мобильная-версия

Вот скриншот (в самом низу профиля):

> [image: Скриншот]

Comment: Это одна из [адовых строк для перевода](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301810/339911), об которую не хочется мараться (снова и снова).

Comment: @alexout, жаль.